What does $[S]^k$ mean if $S$ is a set?
I am trying to understand a statement of Ramsey's theorem quoted by Karen R. Johannson in "Variations on a theorem by van der Waerden". She states,
For every $k, m, r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ there is an integer $n$ so that for any set $S$ with $|S|=n$ and any $r$-colouring $\Delta :[S]^k \to [1,r]$ there is a set $T \in [S]^m$ such that $[T]^k$ is monochromatic.
I am not sure what the author means by $[S]^k$ and the relation that $T \in [S]^m$.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Here's a link to Johannson's work (which you should have included in your post): https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/vdw/othervdwbook.pdf

The notation you ask about is defined on Page 8. Please look it up, and post it as an answer to your question.

If this post gets reopened, it could be reclosed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678753 (though this was the converse question)

I am at a loss to understand why this question was closed.

Now that the question has been reopened, mathy, you can post an answer to it.

Thank you I just did.

I am sorry to have forgotten to check the "terminology" section of the paper. Indeed Johannson has pointed out the following:
$[S]^k$ is any subset of set $S$ with cardinality $k$. Mathematically,
$$[S]^k :=\{A\subseteq S: |A|=k\}.$$
In graph theoretic language, what Ramsey is saying is the following:
There always exists a natural number $n$ such that any $r$-coloring of $K_n$ results in a monochromatic clique $K_m$.
