Denote k-multi-subset
For a given set $A$, I would like to denote the set of k-multi-subsets, i.e., $B=[b_1, \ldots, b_n]$ satisfying $b_i\in A$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, allowing $b_i=b_j$ for any $i,j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. My suggestion is
$$ A^{k}=\left[B: b_i \in A,  i\le k \right]$$
I am writing in the graph theory/combinatorics domain. Is there some standard/preferred notation for this or does mine suffice?
Edit: Added the constraint that my outputs $B$ are ordered, like a vector $B\in \mathbb R^k$.

How much research on such a notation have you done? Where? And what did you find?

If you want to use something superscriptish, I’d go with the $k$ somewhere in the “base” and the $V$ in the “exponent.” This is consistent with the notation $B^A$ for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ and reflects the fact that multisets can be seen as functions from a ground set to its elements’ multiplicities.

@PaulTanenbaum I've found questions on math-overflow (such as this one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678753/is-there-a-commonly-accepted-notation-for-k-subsets). However, the case in question did not allow for duplicated elements in the output

Precisely that kind of information added to your question would make it stronger and more appropriate here.

If I understand correctly (and assume $k$ and $n$ are the same and so are $A$ and $V$, and assuming “outputs“ has no special meaning, you are asking how to specify the set of $k$-length sequences whose terms are elements of a set $A$. This is essentially* the $k$-fold Cartesian product $A\times\dots\times A$, or $A^k$.
*You aren’t clear about what kind of mathematical objects you’re looking at. Because they are ordered, they aren’t multisets, but whether you want to consider them a sequences, ordered tuples, or functions from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ to $A$, the notation $A^k$ should be fine.
